# I want to be able to use useEffect always that I change the name of my group

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

```
useEffect(() => {
  Axios.get(`https://taskcontrolapp.herokuapp.com/taskcontrol/grupo/${props.id}`)
    .then(response => {
      setGrupo(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}, [])
```

I have a object Grupo{ grupo_id and grupo_nome } and i want to change grupo_nome and make useEffect run again, already tried many variables as parameter and never works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per several articles and the react docs, putting this in useEffect like this is bad practice.

It is recommended you either wrap it in a useCallback that is async, or wrap it in a function inside the useEffect, then call the function in useEffect.

See these articles here:

[The Abramov guy](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

[Official docs on custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function someFunc () {
   await Axios.get(`https://taskcontrolapp.herokuapp.com/taskcontrol/grupo/${props.id}`)
    .then(response => {
      setGrupo(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
 }

someFunc()

 return () => {
   // do some clean up here 
 }

// Note the dependency array here...
}, [props.id, grupo_nome])
```